# Get long from unsigned char* buffer via memcpy

Tags: gcc, memcpy

After I have defined and filled the buffer from binary .exe data --

```
unsigned char *buffer ;         /*buffer*/
buffer = malloc(300) ; /*allocate space on heap*/
fread(buffer, 300, 1, file) ;
```

Then how do I get bytes at position  121--124 of buffer
as a long value?

I have tried

```
long Hint = 0;
memcpy(Hint,  buffer[121], 4);
printf("Hint=x%x\n", Hint);
```

but all I get is an abend on memcpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do that (I put numbers in buffer for the example):

```
unsigned char *buffer ;         /*buffer*/
buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc (300) ; /*allocate space on heap*/

for(int i=0;i<300;i++) /*initialize buffer with numbers for the demo*/
    buffer[i] =  i;

long Hint = 0;
long *h = (long *)&buffer[121];
Hint = *h;
printf("Hint=0x%x\n", Hint);
```

The output for this will be:

```
Hint=0x7c7b7a79
```

Which is the numbers 121-124 in hex.